# Creating Multiple Divs Based on Number Chosen in Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a drop down menu where people choose the number of stores they have. Based on this selection I need to create a div with store information for each location.

For example if they choose 3 stores then three identical divs will show up for them to fill out for each store.

Here is my code for the input and the div.

```
<input form='form1' type='number' name='numberOfLocations' 
    id='numberOfLocations' size="2" maxlength="2" />
<div class='businessSpecifics'>
    <label>URL Extension:</label>
    <br>
    <input form='form1' type='text' name='urlExtension' 
        placeholder="businessname" id='businessSpecificsURL' 
        class='businessSpecifics details' /><span>.byMyCompany.com</span>
    <br>
    <label>Login Email:</label>
    <br>
    <input form='form1' type='email' name='email' 
        placeholder='email' id='businessSpecificsEmail' 
        class='businessSpecifics details' />
    <br>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <br>
    <input form='form1' type='password' name='tempPswd' 
        placeholder="" 
        class='businessSpecifics details' />
    <br>
    <label>Business Website:</label>
    <br>
    <input form='form1' type='text' name='bussinessWebsite' 
        placeholder="Business Website" 
        class='businessSpecifics details' />    
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin to be honest. I am fairly new to code so even pointing me in the right direction would be helpful

Comment: then you are able to do this using `javascript` with or without `jQuery`, if you use `jQuery`, look for the `append()` or `html()` functions. also look for the `val()` function to get the value inside the `input`. after you try that, post what you've tried here so we can help you

Comment: You need something to trigger the action that you want, right? So for example add a button that the user should click to generate the divs. Then, add an event handler for that button: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp . After this is working, you need to first select a parent container (https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and use append() or html() as Joel suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the User has asked for dropdown change I have can provide the below solution which creates unique controls each time when the dropdown selection gets changed:

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hnybuu8e/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectStores" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectStores").change(function(){
   $('.businessSpecifics').remove();
    var number=$("#selectStores option:selected").text();
    var htmlToInsert="";
    for(var i=1;i<=number;i++)
    {
       htmlToInsert='<div class="businessSpecifics">'
    +'<label>URL Extension '+i+':</label>'
    +'<br> <input form="form'+i+'" type="text" name="urlExtension" placeholder="businessname" id="businessSpecificsURL" class="businessSpecifics details" />'
    +'<span>.byMyCompany.com</span>'
    +'<br><label>Login Email '+i+':</label>'
    +'<br><input form=form="form'+i+'" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" id="businessSpecificsEmail" class="businessSpecifics details" />'
    +'<br><label>Password '+i+':</label>'
    +'<br><input form=form="form'+i+'" type="password" name="tempPswd" placeholder="" class="businessSpecificsdetails "/>'
    +'<br><label>Business Website '+i+':</label>'
    +'<br><input form=form="form'+i+'" type="text" name="bussinessWebsite" placeholder="Business Website" class="businessSpecifics details" />'
    +'</div><br/><br/>'; 
       $(htmlToInsert).insertAfter("#selectStores");
     }
});
});
```

See the **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hnybuu8e/2/)**

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! I like the drop down menu idea. My input (now select tag) and the div I want to add are on different bootstrap tabs so I am on tab 1 select the number of stores I have, hit next, go to tab 2 then see the corresponding number of divs on that page. Would this change the code at all? Also am I removing the original div from the html and only adding it in jQuery?

Comment: @tiaNaturally.. See the updated demo and let me know if that is what you want!! Once you select number go to tab2 and you can find the created html in that tab!!

Comment: last question.. how come in the original fiddle the stores show up in descending (3-2-1) order but in the updated one they show up ascending (1-2-3)? what's changed?

Comment: I figured out append is ascending and insertAfter is descending.. strange.

Comment: @tiaNaturally.. it's not about ascending or descending.. `insertAfter` will `insert` very next to the element mentioned and as we used `for loop` it will first insert lower one and then higher one.. we can reverse `for loop` and make it work append according to the required order. Append well directly append into the mentioned `div`.

Comment: Hey @Guruprasad Rao one more question as I am adding more stuff to the code and you have been a great help! :D ... when I first select a number of divs (e.g. 2) then I want to change the number of divs to 3 I will now have 5 divs in my code as the first two don't get included in the new amount. Is there a way to reset the number of divs if the number is changed or to just add on additional divs to get to the total of the new number?

Comment: Hey @tiaNaturally.. if you see the code `$('.businessSpecifics').remove();` this part will remove the `divs` already created on selection change and creates a new div and adds into the page!! I hope this is what you are talking about!!

Comment: @Guruprasas Rao Yes thank you! I had to change it to .empty(); because remove must have taken away the whole div and the stores would not load. Again, thank you so much for all your help! It is really appreciated :)

Comment: Anytime!! Happy coding.. :) and yea That works too!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
  $("#numberOfLocations").change(function(){
       var value = $(this).val();
       $(".blockContainer").empty();
       for(var i = 0; i<value; i++){
            var block = $("<div>",{class:"block"});
            $(block).append($("div.businessSpecifics").html());
            $(".blockContainer").append(block);
         }
    }); 
  
 });
```

```css
div.businessSpecifics{
  display:none;    
}
.block{
  width:160px;
  height:200px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  margin:10px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 7px #000;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type='number' name='numberOfLocations' id='numberOfLocations' size="2" maxlength="2" />
<div class="blockContainer"></div>
<div class='businessSpecifics'>
    <label>URL Extension:</label>
    <br>
    <input  type='text' name='urlExtension' 
        placeholder="businessname" id='businessSpecificsURL' 
        class='businessSpecifics details' /><span>.byMyCompany.com</span>
    <br>
    <label>Login Email:</label>
    <br>
    <input  type='email' name='email' 
        placeholder='email' id='businessSpecificsEmail' 
        class='businessSpecifics details' />
    <br>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <br>
    <input  type='password' name='tempPswd' 
        placeholder="" 
        class='businessSpecifics details' />
    <br>
    <label>Business Website:</label>
    <br>
    <input  type='text' name='bussinessWebsite' 
        placeholder="Business Website" 
        class='businessSpecifics details' />    
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code! I really liked your design concept but it just didn't work with the layout of my current form.

Comment: make **width:300px;** instead of "160px" in the **.block** class in CSS file.That will give you the exact layout that you want

Answer (score 0):

On focusout, get the value entered and append the cloned element:

```js
$('#numberOfLocations').on('focusout', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var val = that.val(); 
  for (i=1;i<=val;i++) {
    var c = $('.businessSpecifics').not('.cloned').clone().addClass('cloned');  
    $('#blockHolder').append(c);
  }
});
```

```css
.businessSpecifics:not(.cloned) {  
  display: none;
 }

.businessSpecifics.cloned { 
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding: 10px;
}

#blockHolder {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input form='form1' type='number' name='numberOfLocations' id='numberOfLocations' size="2" maxlength="2" />
<div id="blockHolder" />
<div class='businessSpecifics'>
                    <label>URL Extension:</label>
                    <br>
                    <input form='form1' type='text' name='urlExtension' placeholder="businessname" id='businessSpecificsURL' class='businessSpecifics details' /><span>.byMyCompany.com</span>
                    <br>
                    <label>Login Email:</label>
                    <br>
                    <input form='form1' type='email' name='email' placeholder='email' id='businessSpecificsEmail' class='businessSpecifics details' />
                    <br>
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <br>
                    <input form='form1' type='password' name='tempPswd' placeholder="" class='businessSpecifics details' />
                    <br>
                    <label>Business Website:</label>
                    <br>
                    <input form='form1' type='text' name='bussinessWebsite' placeholder="Business Website" class='businessSpecifics details' />

                </div>
```

Comment: I think that feeding her the code doesn't really help her learn. Please add explanations and point her to documentation as well :)