# Multiple Divs based on selected number (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, controller

I have a problem with my code. According to another post: ([Creating Multiple Divs Based on Number Chosen in Drop Down Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798950/creating-multiple-divs-based-on-number-chosen-in-drop-down-menu?fbclid=IwAR1eiykxpU1t5n9zt_Ht2atLiGzv4sqDsisFrcXg2O8PO84QBs7VPn_yzX0) )
I have taken some ideas for my code but I have an issue. I want to insert into my datbase all the inputs from the created divs, but it records only the last div's inputs. This is my controller setup:

```
$generals= new Instance;

$generalsnames=implode("",$_POST['generalname']);

$generalstime=implode("",$_POST['generaltime']);

$generals->Name= $generalsnames;

$generals->Time= $generaltime;

$generals->save();
```

Can you help me? Thank you in advice

Comment: can you provide the data you want to save? and the code of where the div gonna come from.

Comment: I answered in anotther comment. Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

I mixed the solutions by @Jovs and @rkg. After a few tweeks and restarting the server I got it working. Steps Followed:

- Added `[]` into the name tags, in the blade.php
- In the controller I put the code of @Jovs (in the for statement you missed a " ' ")

```php
$input = $request->all();
for($i=0; $i<count($input['generalname']); $i++){
   $generals= new Instance;
   $generals->Name= $input['generalname'][$i];
   $generals->Time= $input['generaltime'][$i];
   $generals->save();
}
```

I got the "Array into string conversion" issue. I really didn't touched anything. I've just restarted the server, but later I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML(blade) code, add "[]" on your field names. So your field names should be as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="generalname[]">
<input type="text" name="generaltime[]">
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" name="generalname">
<input type="text" name="generaltime">
```

because only the last value of appended divs with such names will be included in your POST request to your route if you haven't specified an array for the names of your fields.

Then in your controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $input = $request->all();
   //you might want to combine your arrays for easier saving
   $general_time = array_combine($input['generalname'], $input['generaltime']);

   //then you will use foreach statement to save all of your data
   foreach($general_time as $general => $time)
   {
      $generals = new Instance;
      $generals->Name = $general;
      $generals->Time = $time
      $generals->save();
   }
}
```

Comment: I did it! The problem now, is that I have all results into one row, instead of multiple rows... How can I write different rows for each divs?

Comment: Use a foreach statement and don't implode the array because imploding it will result into a string, thus a single record will only be written on the database.

Comment: I have to set up foreach statement in oth HTML and php side?

Answer (score 0):

as @rkg mentioned you need `[]` in your blade, then on your controller this will be your code.

```
$input = $request->all();
for($i=0; $i<count($input['generalname']); $i++)
{
    $generals= new Instance;
    $generals->Name= $input['generalname'][$i];
    $generals->Time= $input['generaltime'][$i];
    $generals->save();
}
```

Comment: did you add `[]` to your input name?

Comment: Yes. I did. Like: 
<input class="form-control" name='generalname[]' id="generalname" placeholder="General's Name"/><br>

Comment: oh I think because the one you're getting is the id not the name. Try to do it in a name of the input not the id.

Comment: sorry i didn't quite understand. Do I have to add "[]" in the id's too?

Comment: No does your jquery pass the data to controller or you have a form that pass it in controller?

Comment: I think my jquery just add multiple divs, and different forms pass datas into controller. I'm not very expert in jquery etc... I copied the jquery code from another post, just to create different divs.

Comment: try to use dd(request->all()); and see if your input is getting it all

Comment: Oh. I actually see two different rows for each generalname and generaltime:
  "instances" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Test"
  ]
  "generalname" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1111"
    1 => "2222"
  ]
  "generaltime" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "-10"
    1 => "-6"
  ]

I think i'm solving it. What am I missing..? Thank you

Comment: Actually the datas are inserting to database. Everytime i reload, i got different rows in database , with the right datas that i put. But i still got the Array to string conversion problem... Why that?